# Store a column from csv excel file to a vector double variable C++

Tags: c++, csv, vector, ifstream

I have a csv file in Excel that has a column of double data. I am trying to read that column and store the values in a vector variable using a while loop. I tried to use getline and then convert them into a double using stod.

The column has more values, but this is how the csv file looks like:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 51.32 |  |
| 53.62 |  |

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream myFile("CData.csv");

    int i= 0;
    string val;

    std::vector<double> y;

    while (getline(myFile, val, ',')) {
     y.push_back(stod(val));
     cout << "test: " << y.at(i);
     i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Somehow, there is no output on the console app. I tried it with string ang it worked but when I try to convert to a double, it doesn't. Is there another way to do this, or did I miss something in the code? Thanks, I'm new to coding.

Comment: you need to at least check that you opened the filr

Comment: My guess is you either put `CData.csv` in the wrong folder or named it differently. Remember `c++` won't search for your file name. You must tell it exactly where to look or to put the file in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first parse the line and then look at the line for comma separated data. Also you need to chek if data is digits or not.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream myFile("CData.csv", std::ios::in);

    int i= 0;
    string val;
    std::string line;
    std::vector<double> y;    
    while (getline(myFile, line)) 
    {
        std::stringstream sstr(line);
        while (getline(sstr, val, ',')) 
        {
            bool flag = true;        
            for (auto c : val)
                if (!isdigit(c))
                    flag = false;
            
            if (flag){
                y.push_back( std::stod(val));
                std::cout << "number: " << y.at(i) << std::endl;
                i++;
            }
            else std::cout << "not number: " << val << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Good luck!